# Unable to write my own iterator based on an STL iterator

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator

I have a little problem while trying to implement a container, Set, based on a linked list.
Yeah, I know that there's an STL implementation of a set, but this is for homework. :)

So, this is what I have done so far:

my Set.h file looks like that:

```
template <class T>
class Set {
private:
    typedef std::list<T> base_container;
    base_container items;
public:
    class myIterator {
    public:
        typename base_container::iterator base_iterator;
        myIterator() { }
    };
    void addItem(const T item) {
        items.push_back(item);
    }
    typedef typename Set<T>::myIterator setIterator;
    setIterator begin() { return items.begin(); }
    setIterator end() { return items.end(); }
    Set<T>(void) { }
    ~Set<T>(void) { }
};
```

Now, main.cpp:

```
#include "Set.h"

int main(void) {
    Set<int> mySet;

    mySet.addItem(1);
    mySet.addItem(2);
    mySet.addItem(3);
    mySet.addItem(4);

    Set<int>::myIterator x;
    x = mySet.begin();       // produces an error about non-convertible types.

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
error C2664: 'Set<T>::myIterator::myIterator(const Set<T>::myIterator &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' to 'const Set<T>::myIterator &'
```

Clearly I messed things up, but I'm not sure which part of the code is actually the problem.
Any suggestions about how to fix this? Any helpful information will be appreciated.

Thanks. :)

Comment: It would help to see the error message

Comment: oh, yeah, of course, sorry:
error C2664: 'Set<T>::myIterator::myIterator(const Set<T>::myIterator &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' to 'const Set<T>::myIterator &'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems with your approach.

As others have said, you can't create your iterator type from the underlying type:

```
setIterator begin() { return items.begin(); }
setIterator end() { return items.end(); }
```

This can be solved by adding a constructor to your type:

```
class myIterator {
    typedef typename base_container::iterator base_iterator_type;
public:
    explicit myIterator(base_iterator_type i) : base_iterator(i) { }
    base_iterator_type base_iterator;
    myIterator() { }
};
```

This constructor should be explicit, which means you need to change how you create it:

```
setIterator begin() { return setIterator(items.begin()); }
```

The next problem is that your type doesn't implement the iterator interface, it doesn't provide `operator++` or `operator*` etc. and it doesn't define nested types such as `value_type` and `iteratory_category` i.e. it's not an iterator (just giving it a name with "iterator" in it doesn't make it true!)

Once you fix that and your type is a valid iterator, you'll find your container can't be used with STL-style algorithms because it doesn't implement the container requirements. Among other things, it should provide a nested type called `iterator` not `setIterator` so that other template code can use `S::iterator` without caring if `S` is a `std::set<T>` or a `Set<T>`.  Don't call it `Set<T>::setIterator`, just call it `Set<T>::iterator`.  Also in this case there's no point defining `myIterator` (noone cares that it's yours! :-) then having a typedef  to call it `setIterator`, just name the type with the right name in the first place and you don't need a typedef.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive from `std::iterator<T>` and provide the approprate iterator category tag. This will automatically give your iterator the required nested types such as `value_type` in terms of `T`. You will still need to write function members such as `operator++` and `operator*` (depending on your iterator category, e.g. you also need `operator[]` for random access iterators)

Comment: but won't give it `operator++` or `operator*`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
setIterator begin() { return items.begin(); }
setIterator end() { return items.end(); }
```

The values you're trying to return have the wrong type. They are of type `base_iterator` and not `setIterator`, and there's no way to implicitly convert from the former to the latter.

Comment: OK, so how can I 'offer' an stl-like iterator? is deriving from std::iterator the only way for accomplishing that?

Comment: @Catalyst: The easiest is probably to encapsulate the underlying iterator in your iterator. Then you might wish to consider having a conversion constructor in your iterator class.

Comment: @Catalyst no, you don't actaully need to inherit from `std::iterator`. It is merely a helper class which gives you a few things for free, but you don't actually *need* it to create a STL-compatible iterator. You just have to expose the right typedefs, specialize the right traits, and overload the right iterators.